# Deployment price

Tags: solana-program, devnet, deploy, mainnet

I planning to launch my program on the mainnet. Do you know if I can expect the same deployment cost on the mainnet compared to the devnet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Devnet and mainnet have no differences in terms of program deployment costs. Devnet is intended to be functionally equivalent to mainnet, with the exception of airdrop.